# How can I perform a double interpolation of a table?

Tags: interpolation

I have a data table representing a two-variable function $c(f,r)$. $f$, $r$ and $c$ are all non-negative. The table is organised as follows:

- The first column contains different values of $r$.
- Each of the other columns contains the values of $c(f,r)$ for a different value of $f$ (column 2 is $c(0.020,r)$, column 3 is $f(0.025,r)$, column 4 is $c(0.030,r)$ and so on).

[image]

I'd like to perform a double interpolation (I don't currently care about interpolation order or method, that's fine-tuning for later) of this data in order to have a continuous function $c(f,r)$.

This is what I tried and didn't work:

First, I separated the data into columns starting from the second one, joined each column to the first one and interpolated that:

```
PYdata=ReadList["PY.txt",Number,RecordLists->True];
For[j=2,j<=Dimensions[PYdata][[2]],j++,
  PYcol=Transpose[Join[{PYdata[[All,1]],PYdata[[All,j]]}]];
  PYfun[0.02+0.005(j-2)]=Interpolation[PYcol];
];
```

This worked just fine:

[image]

What this left me with was a bunch of functions `PYfun[f][r]` of $r$ for specific values of $f$. Next, I thought I'd make a table of these and interpolate the table:

```
c[f_,r_]:=Interpolation[Table[Join[{f,PYfun[f][r]}],{f,0.02, 0.4,0.005}]];
```

This is the part that didn't work. I thought that calling `c[f,r]` for an arbitrary value of $r$ would create a table of `PYfun[f][r]` for that value of $r$, interpolate in $f$ and return the value of $c$ obtained from that interpolation (probably not the most efficient way of doing things, and graphing anything would probably take forever). However, it seems it isn't even able to do the interpolation. Here's what happened when I asked it to graph $c(f,r)$:

[image]

I'm at a loss. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, I figured it out! Contrary to what I thought, Mathematica *can* interpolate multidimensional data as long as the data is in the specific format `{{{x1,y1,...},f1},{{x2,y2,...},f2},...}`. In my case, it's `{{{r1,f1},c(f1,r1)},{{r2,f2},c(f2,r2)},...}`.

Here's the code that worked:

```
c=Interpolation[Flatten[Table[{{PYdata[[j,1]],0.02+0.005(l-2)},PYdata[[j,l]]},{j,1,Dimensions[PYdata][[1]]},{l,2,Dimensions[PYdata][[2]]}],1]];
```

It works, as shown in the graph below:

[image]